# Как реальзовать слайдер с затемнением элементов на основе slick-slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js, img

Пытаюсь сверстать макет сайта и дошёл до секции со слайдером на макете она выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил использовать `slick-slider`, но никак не могу понять как можно реализовать так, чтобы следующий и предыдущий элементы отображались как на макете.

Пробовал отображать по 3 слайда но не получается выделить уникальный селектор у центрального слайда чтобы на остальные наложить соответствующий CSS класс, пробовал рулить свойством `centerPadding`, но тоже особых успехов не добился.

Mожет быть кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей или знает направление в котором двигаться для её решения?

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.carousel').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  });
})
```

```css
.slick-slide .slick-active+.slick-active~.slick-active {
  display: block;
  padding: 150px 15px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scale(.9);
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.slick-active+.slick-active {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="carousel__slide">
  <img src="img/t1.png" alt="t1png" class="sl__img">
  <div class="sl__text">
    <h3 class="sl__zag">Анисимова Ольга</h3>
    <p class="sl__desc">Хочу рассказать о компании Global Opt. Самое главное что меня радует, это быстрый поиск и анализ определенного товара. Доставляла через компанию уже много раз, от расходных материалов для отеля, ло дольших партий детской одежды. Буду продолжать пользтваьбся
      услугами даной компании</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="carousel__slide">
  <img src="img/t1.png" alt="t1png" class="sl__img">
  <div class="sl__text">
    <h3 class="sl__zag">Анисимова Ольга</h3>
    <p class="sl__desc">Хочу рассказать о компании Global Opt. Самое главное что меня радует, это быстрый поиск и анализ определенного товара. Доставляла через компанию уже много раз, от расходных материалов для отеля, ло дольших партий детской одежды. Буду продолжать пользтваьбся
      услугами даной компании</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="carousel__slide">
  <img src="img/t1.png" alt="t1png" class="sl__img">
  <div class="sl__text">
    <h3 class="sl__zag">Анисимова Ольга</h3>
    <p class="sl__desc">Хочу рассказать о компании Global Opt. Самое главное что меня радует, это быстрый поиск и анализ определенного товара. Доставляла через компанию уже много раз, от расходных материалов для отеля, ло дольших партий детской одежды. Буду продолжать пользтваьбся
      услугами даной компании</p>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что в итоге у меня получается, вроде все ошибки исправил.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('.carousel').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  });
})
```

```css
.slick-slide,
.slick-active + .slick-active ~ .slick-active{
  display: block;
  padding: 150px 15px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  transform: scale(.9);
  opacity: 0.7;
  
  transition: .5s ease ;
}

.slick-active + .slick-active{
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 1</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 2</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 3</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 4</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 5</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 6</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 7</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 8</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 9</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 10</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 11</div>
  <div class="carousel__slide">slide 12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня почему то, нет увеличения среднего слайда, только темнеет фон у правого крайнего, а 2 боковых остаются неизменными, с чем это может быть связано? Может я не туда подключал что то? Если не сложно можете расписать ваш код, что куда нужно подключать? Что в css, что в html, что в js? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Выложите сюда код своего слайдера.

Comment: Написал код, в проблеме выше

Comment: В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Запятую после .slick-slide в первой строке SASS забыли поставить.
А также проверьте box-sizing:border-box для элементов карусели

Comment: Я добавил скриншот моей карусели, ошибки исправил, не работает((

Comment: не исправили ошибку

Comment: А что именно я должен был сделать с box-sizing:border-box ?)

Comment: Во-первых — не поставили запятую. Если Вы не знаете, что делать с border-box – перестаньте использовать препроцессоры и учите css

Comment: Да поставил я запятую, я не переписывал тут код, я у себя поставил, а про border-box я знаю, просто мне это ничего не дает, сам слайдер у меня работает, но проблема в том что у меня почему то, нет увеличения среднего слайда